# SQL query joining rows with same value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that creates a view that calculates the total cost of each sale, by considering quantity and price of each bought item. The view should return the debit and total cost.

**In the answer each debit-number should only occur once.**

Thanks in advance

**Table ITEM:**

```
ID       NAME       PRICE
118      Jeans      100
120      Towel      20
127      Shirt      55
```

**Table DEBIT:**

```
DEBIT     ITEM     Quantity
100581    118      5
100581    120      1
100586    127      5
```

Comment: How are these tables related? IS it ITEM->ID?

Comment: I have tried the following: SELECT debid, (item.price * debit.quantity) AS "Total Price" FROM debit, item WHERE debit.item = item.id

Comment: @Slinky, yes. The ITEM is related with ID.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this using a simple JOIN;

```
SELECT d.DEBIT, SUM(d.Quantity*i.Price) SUM
FROM DEBIT d
JOIN ITEM i ON d.ITEM=i.ID
GROUP BY d.DEBIT;
```

Simple demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a7fb/7).

Answer (score 2):

How about -

```
SELECT DEBIT.DEBIT, SUM(`ITEM`.`PRICE` * `DEBIT`.`Quantity`)
FROM `ITEM`
INNER JOIN `DEBIT`
    ON `ITEM`.`ID` = `DEBIT`.`ITEM`
GROUP BY `DEBIT`.`DEBIT`
```

Comment: Around here we say thanks by accepting the answer that we use. Please accept @Joachim's answer as he made the effort to set up the demo.

Answer (score -2):

something like this would work...

```
SELECT d.id,SUM(i.price*d.quantity) as total_cost
FROM item i join debit d 
on i.id=d.item_id 
group by d.id;
```

Comment: You don't want to group by `i.price,d.quantity`.

Comment: yeah..i knw..written by mistake..!!